# Mega slide out menu

Tags: css, navigation, nav

Hi guys i want to create a sort of mega slide out menu from a vertical menu but having a few difficulties doing so.

My html for the nav is a bog standard 3 tier menu e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1 Item 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 3 Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 3 Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 3 Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 3 Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 Item 5</a></li>
    </li>
```

What i would like is illustrated in the image below:

[image: Example Image]

I have the nav in place where i want it and i have it so when i hover over a 1st level item the 2nd level shows. Im just not sure on how to get the 3rd level to show underneatht he 2nd level items

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Sorry guys forgot the CSS here's what i have, whether its correct for what i need to know im not sure:

```
.nav-container {float:left;}
#nav { width:220px; height:260px; font-size:13px;}

#nav li { text-align:left; list-style-type: none; position:relative; }

#nav li > ul {display:none;}

 #nav li:hover > ul{
     width:676px;
     height:260px;
     display: block;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:9999;
     left:220px;
     top:auto;
 }
 #nav ul li {
     padding:0 20px;
     display:inline;
 }
```

At the moment this css positions the 1st level correctly and the second level shows in correct position with 2nd level items positioned correctly, im just not sure how to go about positioning the 3rd level items under the 2nd level items

**EDIT 2**

I have structured the nav as you guys have said, just didnt type it correctly!, i have edited the post to show this, thanks

Comment: are you asking us from a design POV? Visual/User Interaction? If so, this would be best asked on either the UX site or GD site.

Comment: HTML here is irrelevant without your current CSS code or a fiddle or something...

Comment: BTW, I would recommend setting your `li` structure up with `ul`s for every further tier...

Comment: So, do you have any static sizes we know about? Do you want your widths and whatnot positioned that way?

Comment: The first level nav is 220px width and the flyout out on hover is 656px wide. and thats it at the moment. The nav is in a main container which is 896px wide, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a good jumping off point with the code provided.

**First problem, your structure.**

Use a structure like this, as it will make it MUCH easier to target and style your levels deeper into the tree.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/hz45B/6/

- Level 1

  - Level 2

    - Level 3
    - Level 3
  - Level 2

    - Level 3
    - Level 3
- Level 1

  - Level 2

    - Level 3
    - Level 3
  - Level 2

    - Level 3
    - Level 3

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    padding:25px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    list-style:none;
    width:100px;
}
ul ul {
    display:none;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/hz45B/6/

**Once you're at this point, for your third `ul` list, just apply this CSS:**

*make sure to have your `ul` `ul` set at `position: relative;`*

```
ul ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

**Dirty Example, but you get the point:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/hz45B/7/

Comment: Oh i thought there was more information! haha. This hasnt answered my question of how to get the third level nav items positioned directly under the 2nd level nav items like shown in the image i provided, thanks

Comment: The code I added to the post at the base should make that work.

Comment: Wait a second... here is your fiddle? Where is all of your styling? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/hz45B/8/). Maybe I'm confused?